# The easiest way to develop the Yeoman generator's template itself

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

#### Sample situation

- I have my own [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) generator, which has a folder with "template" of the resulting project.
- The generator takes some information from user, interpolates the "template" with the information and then outputs a simple working project.
- I want to ensure the "template" is actually working, at least in one positive scenario if not with all combination of inputs. I can write [integration tests](http://yeoman.io/authoring/testing.html) (which will run the generator with some data and then try to run the resulting code and verify whether all works as expected), but still, that's sometimes too much work and it's inconvenient for trial and error kind of development or some prototyping.

#### Question

Is there an easy way how to work with the "template" itself, how to run it or use it locally, manually, without the need to run the generator first every time I change a single letter in files of the "template"?

Maybe some sort of build step, which would run the generator for me with some preset data? Is there anything ready in form of npm module? Does a best practice exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the best solution I found is to create a script, which:

1. Creates a temporary sandbox directory.
2. Performs `npm link`
3. Alters the `PATH` so it does **not** contain `.bin` of your local `node_modules` (this is needed to prevent locally installed Yeoman take precedence over the global one when the script is ran e.g. as `npm run develop`).
4. Sets an environment value `NON_INTERACTIVE` to something truthy.
5. Runs `yo <your generator>` in the sandbox directory.
6. Runs `npm start` in the sandbox directory to run the freshly generated server code.

Change your generator so it is able to automatically provide some dummy default values for required prompts without default values if `process.env.NON_INTERACTIVE` is truthy.

Then run the script as:

```
$ nodemon --watch <directory with your template> --exec <path to your script> --ext js
```

It's slow, but it works. This way you can develop the template itself and avoid filling the generator every time you need to try out something.

Answer (score 0):

After running the integration test, you can spawn some commands in the generated project folder and see if those are passing fine.